# UI thread stops because of adding a picture

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, image, user-interface

I have some trouble with reporting the progress of multiple uploads. At the moment I generate mock data and the upload is a background worker with a simple for loop counting from 0 to 100 delayed in each loop. To realise the upload I'm using two object types. One for the entire upload (transferObj) which contains a list of upload objects for each file (uploadFileObj). The uploadFileObj contains the backgroud worker. To report the progress I simply bind the current progress property of the uploadFileObj to the different progressbars.
One progress bar for the entire upload and one for each file which is uploaded async.

**uploadFileObj**:

```
 _backGroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _backGroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        _backGroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        _backGroundWorker.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
        {
            for (int k = 0; k <= 100; k++)
            {
                while (DoPause)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleep);
                (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(k);
            }
        };
        _backGroundWorker.ProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            this.CurrentProgress = e.ProgressPercentage;
        };
        _backGroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if ((e.Cancelled == true))
                Console.WriteLine("Canceled!");
            else if (!(e.Error == null))
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
            else
            {
                IsFinished = true;
            }
        };

        _backGroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Everything works fine so far. The Progress will be reported in the UI thread for each file and the entire upload. 
But when I add a png image on the custom control which is hosting the progress bars, the UI thread stop till all the background worker are finished.

Why does that happen?

Comment: I would recommend you to edit your question & add some more tags like (C#,threads,dispatcher. It will increase visibility of your question.

Comment: What is the source of the PNG image? Is it bound to something or is it static?

Comment: It's not bound. I simply add it static, for example to the background of the user control. <Image Source="../graphics/icon_close_self_blue_25x25.png"/>